# Unreal Engine 5 Compilation Errors

Tags: compilation, unreal-engine5

"I'm encountering multiple errors in Unreal Engine 5 during compilation, but I don't have an error code to provide while packaging and also cooking the game.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwKht.png)"[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BU8b.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqIwV.jpg)

Here is my Project:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Kx0AChTpQK-kymOQWNTlVzpI2tnghxcG?usp=sharing

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance you could offer. Thank you in advance for your help!

Feel free to adjust it to better suit your tone or preferences!

I've attempted various approaches, including pre-cooking, different packaging methods, and importing and exporting anew, but the issues persist.